# GitLab Pipeline: MSBuild Succeeds Project But Fails to Publish Properly, How to Automate Deployment to Production VM?

Tags: gitlab, devops, solution

I have a GitLab pipeline set up for my project using MSBuild, and it seems to be building successfully. However, when it comes to publishing the project, it fails to do so properly. I've checked all configurations, paths, and permissions, but still can't figure out why it's failing to publish correctly.

Why might the project be failing to publish properly despite successful build?

Assuming I can fix the publishing issue, what would be the best approach to automatically deploy the published project to my production VM once it's successfully published? Should I use GitLab's CI/CD capabilities, or are there better methods for this?